# I'm having troubles reading an excel file in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to read an excel file(xlsx), I defined the path using

```
$uri = "public/storage/resultsheet/Revival Royal Academy_Primary 5B_1572753672.xlsx";
```

but I keep getting the error

> File "public/storage/resultsheet/Revival Royal Academy_Primary 5B_1572753672.xlsx"

does not exist. I'm new to this framework.

This is the controller code.

```
public function show($id)    
{
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();

    $reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
    $uri = "public/storage/resultsheet/Revival Royal Academy_Primary 5B_1572753672.xlsx";

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($uri);
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    return view('student.result', compact('worksheet'));
}
```

Comment: maybe it wants an absolute path not a relative path

Comment: I recommend obscuring your filename for privacy purposes.

Comment: Thanks @developerjack for your recommendation. Duly noted

Answer (score 0):

The path you're using is relative to the *current directory* that PHP is running in. For Laravel, that likely means you'll be running this in `app/Services/MyUploadService.php` or something similar.

Given your path is relative, PhpOffice will probably be trying to load `app/Services/public/storage... etc.' which is incorrect.

Laravel has helper methods that can assist you in working with paths within your app.

You could look at using `base_dir()` (so: `base_dir('public/storage/example.xlsx').`) as it will give you an absolute path, and a similar usage of `public_path()` would be better than that.

However, best out of all the options would be using `storage_path()`. So your code would instead read:

```php
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
    $uri = storage_path("resultsheet/my.xlsx");

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($uri);
```

There's helpful documentation on the [Path helpers in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#paths).

To debug this, storing `realpath('subdir/example.txt')` etc. in a variable and using a debugging tool will help you figure out the relative/absolute paths in your project and server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used the public_path() and it's working perfectly

Comment: Excellent! To help others, you can upvote the answer :)